# How can I use a list of wildcard match in SQL?

Tags: sql, hiveql, wildcard

I have a SQL code :

```
       CASE
     WHEN job_title LIKE '%Temp%'
           OR job_title LIKE '%Intern%'
           OR job_title LIKE '%Substitute%' THEN true
     ELSE false
   END   AS is_part_time,
```

I wanted to know if there is a cleaner way to do this, is it possible to use a list of wildcards similar to IN clause? Something like this?

```
       CASE
     WHEN job_title LIKE ['%Temp%','%Intern%','%Substitute%'] THEN true
     ELSE false
   END   AS is_part_time,
```

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using regular expressions and simplify this using `RLIKE` eg

```sql
 CASE
     WHEN job_title RLIKE '.*(Temp|Intern|Substitute).*' THEN true
     ELSE false
 END   AS is_part_time,
```

or simply

```
job_title RLIKE '.*(Temp|Intern|Substitute).*' AS is_part_time
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Is there a need for `CASE WHEN` statement at all? Doesn't `RLIKE` already return `TRUE` or `FALSE`?

Comment: @ReinisVerbelis I've included the simplification

Answer (score 0):

You can phrase this using regular expressions:

```
(job_title rlike 'Temp|Intern|Substitute') as is_part_time
```

Note:  You should really have a table with valid job titles.  That table should have columns that specify characteristics of the job, such as `is_part_time`.